# Firebase UI Demo AND Login with Google PopUp Results in blank Pop Up on Windows 11

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, windows-11

**Operating System:** Windows 11 (Up to date with Updates)

**Browser version:** Chrome Latest, Firefox Latest, Edge Latest

**Firebase UI version:** Latest

**Firebase SDK version:** 9.13.0

**The Problem**

https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/

Using the above Demo, the popup for Google, FB, Twitter and Github is blank.

Using the above Demo, the redirect for Google, FB, Twitter and Github leads to a blank page.

**Steps to reproduce:**

Attempt to open the URL: https://fir-ui-demo-84a6c.firebaseapp.com/ in any browser on Windows 11

**Things to note,**

There are no errors in the console when the page is loaded and after the relevant button is clicked.

I have tested the URL in all latest browsers on Windows 10 and the Pop UP and Redirect WORKS

I have tested the URL in all latest browsers on OSX Ventura and the Pop Up and Redirect WORKS

Auth Provider has been set to Google in Firebase Auth
No AdBlockers or other extensions are installed in any of the browsers

Just not working on Windows 11

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MARbh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there may be a number of things that can cause this. I think that at least one of the causes is using FirebaseUI from a non-secure domain (HTTP rather than HTTPS).  Although, from your question, it looks like this is not what is causing it in your case as you are hosting the demo under HTTPS, but for others who may land here...

My own experience is that while developing on localhost, running on HTTP, I see this behavior and am unable to use "Sign in with Google", etc.  When I take the exact same code and test it from an HTTPS host domain (in my case I just publish it to Firebase Hosting) it works.

It is also worth double checking your authorized domains, authorized origins, authorized redirect URIs, etc. configured with your identity providers.  For Google, for example, you might:

1. Go to your projects credentials console page (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Under "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs" select the client you are using for FirebaseUI
3. Review your "Authorized JavaScript origins" and "Authorized redirect URIs"

Firebase Authentication also maintains a list of "Authorized domains" that is worth checking when troubleshooting this sort of stuff.  From the Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/):

1. Select your project, select "Authentication" in the left side nav
2. Select the "Settings" tab along the top
3. Then select "Authorized domains"